# How can I reset an option group in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am monitoring true/false veterinarian cases in a research facility. I have a true/false option group that generates either 1 (true) or 2 (false). Then, I use the value (which is not stored in any table) to create specific actions. Here is my form:

[image]

I would like the True/False option group to reset to no value when a new record is created. Otherwise, the value stays the same for each new record. Do I need to store the value in a variable to accomplish this? I would prefer not to be the case as I want my database to be as streamlined as possible.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you create a new record? With a command button? Or simply by navigating to a new record with the standard `>*` button?

If you have your own function, add

```
Me!optTrueFalse = Null
```

in there.

If you don't, you can put it into `Form_BeforeInsert`, but it will happen when you start typing, not when navigating to the new record. This is how unbound controls work.